# Trouble to execute sample code using fastText

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, fasttext

### Background

I would like to execute the code to categorize language of each text using fastText.

#### What I have done

- downloaded the model `lid.176.bin`
  https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/language-identification.html
- installed the python binding

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
$ cd fastText
$ pip install .
```

The above the model `lid.176.bin` and the folder `fastText` are located on the same level as the below python code exists.

I have no idea how to avoid the error.

### Error

```
ImportError: No module named fastText
```

### Code

sample.py

```py
from fastText import load_model
model = load_model("lid.176.bin")

speech_texts = ["Hello, guys. What's up?", '你好! 我是学生。', 'Hallo, ich habe das Buch.']

def categorize(texts):
    for i in range(len(texts)):
        text = texts[i]
        label, prob = model.predict(text, k)
        return list(zip([l.replace("__label__", "") for l in label], prob))

categorize(speech_texts)
```

### Response to the answer

1. I have tried to execute the command following the answer, but still I am struggling to fix the same error.

```sh
$ pip3 install fasttext
Requirement already satisfied: fasttext in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.9.2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fasttext) (51.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fasttext) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from fasttext) (2.6.1)
```

```
    from fasttext import load_model
ImportError: No module named fasttext
```

2. packages that I have installed

```
$ pip3 freeze
fasttext @ file:///Users/username/Desktop/sample/fastText
numpy==1.19.5
pybind11==2.6.1
```

### Develop Environment

Python 3.9

Mac OS Big Sur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a best practice, you should be using Python "virtual environments".

While it's not absolutely necessary to avoid this sort of confusion, by adopting the discipline of keeping your **working python and associated libraries** for a **specific project** separate from the **system python**, lots of things will be explicitly separate & clearer, in your mind & on your filesystem.

Two reasonable ways to use virtual environments would be *either* of:

- the native `venv` facility: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
- the `conda` tool – I specifically prefer the minimalist `miniconda` to explicitly control what & how much is installed: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html (guide to [managing environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-envs))

Once you're in the habit of using explicit environments, problems lik yours tend to disappear after you've verified two things:

1. Had you properly activated the right environment before doing a `pip install PKG`? (In many cases with `conda`, you might prefer `conda install PKG` to get their extra-optimized packages – though standard `pip` works there too.)
2. Are you executing your code within the right (same) environment as the necessary libraries were installed?

If you're using environments, and verify those 2 things, you'll generally stop having confusion about whether your current executing code can use the libraries you've installed.

Your current problem may also be made extra twisty by the fact that on MacOS, both Python 2 and Python 3 coexist – in what are, essentially, different virtual environments. Anything you do with a simple `python` or `pip` invocation uses the default Python 2. By default, to either install in, or execute with, Python 3 you need to use `pip3` and `python3`. Something installed with `pip3` may not be visible to a plain `python` execution, generating errors like what you've hit. (Once you start using true `venv`s of `conda`, it may then become the case that a plain `python` or `pip` invocation, **inside an activated virtual environment**, chooses a Python 3 executable that's right for that environment.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`from fasttext import load_model`

as explained [in the documentation](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python#word-representation-model).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However the terminal returns `from fasttext import load_model
ImportError: No module named fasttext` again.

Comment: Then try first `pip install fasttext`. The installation works or prints some error message?

Comment: please report the output of `pip freeze`

Comment: I added the result of `pip3 freeze` on my post.

Comment: Ok. How do you launch your script? `python3 sample.py` or what?